# How to use real address in foundry anvil

Tags: foundry, anvil

I have a project that operates on Anvil. Previously, I used an account provided by Anvil, but now I wish to use the actual MetaMask address in development. Is there a method to integrate the real address into the Anvil environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if your anvil chain is a fork of a real network, then just use the '--fork-url' and use your desired account from whatever block you want.

Otherwise the local anvil chain is an EVM chain, so the address you want to use still exists, it just won't have any of the history. To send it some Ether, do something like:

`cast send --value $(FUND_AMOUNT) --private-key $(ANVIL_ACCOUNT_0_PRIV_KEY) $(REAL_ADDRESS)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your real account on anvil's local network as well as anvil forked networks.

Here is an example that deploys a contract in a script:

```js
contract DeployYourContract is Script {
    function run() public returns (YourContract) {
        vm.startBroadcast(<YOUR_ADDRESS>);
        YourContract yourContract = new YourContract();
        vm.stopBroadcast();
        return yourContract;
    }
}
```

Then to deploy `YourContract` you can run a command like this:

```js
forge script YourContract --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:8545/ --broadcast --private-key <PRIVATE_KEY>
```

Note: You'll need to send yourself some localhost ETH to pay for any transactions, you can use the `cast` command Peter suggested in [his answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/156207/97149):

```js
cast send --value <AMOUNT> --private-key <ANVIL_PRIVATE_KEY> <YOUR_ADDRESS>
```

Testing using your address is as simple as using [Foundry's prank cheatcode](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/prank):

```js
function Test_FunctionCall() public {
vm.prank(<YOUR_ADDRESS>); 
YourContract.FunctionCall();
}
```